# How to specify width of custom view?

Tags: java, android, view, size, android-view

I'm having trouble trying to set a specific size for the width of my custom view. I know I can just hard-code a value in the `layout_width` field in the `XML` file but I'm trying not to result to hard-coding values. I need my `View` to be half the size of the screen. So, within the `class` I find half the screen size:

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    try{
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
    }catch(NoSuchMethodError e){
        screenWidth = display.getWidth();
    }
```

Then, I call:

```
 measure(width|MeasureSpec.EXACTLY, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT|MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
 //Where width is equal to half the screen width
```

but this does not seem to be working for my case. **So, to sum it all up,** how do you properly specify a particular size for a custom `View`? Any help will be useful and appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the `onMeasure()` method in your Custom View:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels >> 1;
    widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Basically, override the width `MeasureSpec` to be exactly half the width of the screen, then pass that through to the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you might not be able to accurately get the width of the screen at this point because you need to wait till the entire hierarchy (up until the most root view) is laid out. You may need to do something like:

```
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener layoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            //set layoutparams with those values.
            }
        };

getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(layoutListener);
```

You can confirm the correctness of this by seeing if the values you're getting when you try getting the display width inside of onMeasure differ from the values you get when the onGlobalLayout callback is invoked.

Comment: Well, I am able to get the size of the screen width in pixels. the problem I'm having is that when I make a call to the `measure(int width, int height)` method it doesn't seem to make the `View` correspond to the specified values. I'll update my question with how I received the screen size.